# How to generate sequential numbers in xml? (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, sequence, sequences

I have a Python script (2.7) that is generating xml data. However, for each object in my array I need it to generate a new sequential number beginning with 1.

Example below (see sequenceOrder tag):

```
<objectArray>
    <object>
        <title>Title</title>
        <sequenceOrder>1</sequenceOrder>
    </object>
    <object>
        <title>Title</title>
        <sequenceOrder>2</sequenceOrder>
    </object>
    <object>
        <title>Title</title>
        <sequenceOrder>3</sequenceOrder>
    </object>
</objectArray>
```

**With Python 2.7, how can I have my script generate a new number (+1 of the number preceding it) for the sequenceOrder part of each object in my xml array?**

Please note that there will be hundreds of thousands of objects in my array, so something to consider.

I'm totally new to Python/coding in general, so any help is appreciated! Glad to provide additional information as necessary.

Comment: Is title going to remain the same throughout?

Comment: How is your script generating the XML? PLease [edit] your question and add the relevant part of your code.

Comment: @VedangMehta No, but I already have the title part of the script configured.

Comment: @DisplayName added GitHub gist link

Comment: Don't link to external code. Please [edit] your question and include the relevant part of your code.

Comment: @DisplayName too long, can't get it to format properly. Gonna tap out. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating objects to be serialized yourself, you may use [itertools.count](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to get consecutive unique integers.

In a very abstract way it'll look like:

```
import itertools
counter = itertools.count()

o = create_object()
o.sequentialNumber = next(counter)

o2 = create_another_object()
o.sequentialNumber = next(counter)

create_xml_doc(my_objects)
```

Comment: Thanks I will look in to this!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can generate a new sequence number for each XML element. Here is how to produce your sample output using `lxml`:

```
import lxml.etree as et

root = et.Element('objectArray')
for i in range(1, 4):
    obj = et.Element('object')
    title = et.Element('title')
    title.text = 'Title'
    obj.append(title)
    sequenceOrder = et.Element('sequenceOrder')
    sequenceOrder.text = str(i)
    obj.append(sequenceOrder)
    root.append(obj)

print et.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
```

Comment: This presumes knowing your range?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague provided a solution:

set

```
sequence_order = 1
```

then in xml

```
<sequenceOrder>""" + str(sequence_order) + """</sequenceOrder>
```

then later

```
if test is False:
                    with open('uniquetest.csv', 'a') as write:
                        writelog = csv.writer(write, delimiter= '\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
                        writelog.writerow( (title, ) )

                    try:
                        f = open(file + '_output.xml', 'r')
                        f = open(file + '_output.xml', 'a')
                        f.write(DASxml_bottom + DASxml_top + digital_objects) 
                        f.close()
                        sequence_order = sequence_order + 1
#                       f = open('log.txt', 'a')
#                       f.write(title + str(roll) + label_flag + str(id) + str(file_size) + file_path + """
# """) 
#                       f.close()
```

That might make no sense to some since I didn't provide the whole script, but it worked for my purposes! Thanks all for the suggestions